# Compare one row to a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a problem. I have created this code to check how many shared edges my triangle formation has:

```
public class TriangleRegistryList
{
    public float x1 { get; set; }
    public float y1 { get; set; }
    public float x2 { get; set; }
    public float y2 { get; set; }
    public float x3 { get; set; }
    public float y3 { get; set; }
    public int ShapeNum { get; set; }

    public TriangleRegistryList()
    {
        this.AdjacentShapeNumbers = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> AdjacentShapeNumbers { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<(float x, float y)> GetPoints()
    {
        yield return (x1, y1);
        yield return (x2, y2);
        yield return (x3, y3);
    }

    public bool IsAdjacentTo(TriangleRegistryList other)
    {
        var isAdjacentTo =
                    GetPoints().Intersect(other.GetPoints()).Count() >= 2;
        if (isAdjacentTo)
        {
            if(other.ShapeNum != 0)
            {
                AdjacentShapeNumbers.Add(other.ShapeNum);
            }               
        }
        return isAdjacentTo;
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<(T first, T second)> GetPairs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        return list.SelectMany((value, index) => list.Skip(index + 1),
                                (first, second) => (first, second));
    }
}
```

And then I create the list like this:

```
triangles = new List<TriangleRegistryList>();

triangles.Add(new TriangleRegistryList
{
    x1 = (float)405,
    y1 = (float)701.4806,
    x2 = (float)675,
    y2 = (float)701.4806,
    x3 = (float)540,
    y3 = (float)935.3074
});

triangles.Add(new TriangleRegistryList
{
    x1 = (float)135,
    y1 = (float)701.4806,
    x2 = (float)405,
    y2 = (float)701.4806,
    x3 = (float)270,
    y3 = (float)935.3074
});

triangles.Add(new TriangleRegistryList
{
    x1 = (float)270,
    y1 = (float)935.3074,
    x2 = (float)540,
    y2 = (float)935.3074,
    x3 = (float)405,
    y3 = (float)701.4806
});
```

And finally I call the method to compare all the triangle sides with eachother.
    `int sharedEdges = triangles.GetPairs().Where(t => t.first.IsAdjacentTo(t.second)).Count();`

This works great, but now I want to compare 1 triangle to the list, so I can check how many shared edges 1 triangle has with the formation. I already created this loop, but I don't know how to continue:

```
foreach (TriangleRegistryList triangle in triangles)
{
    int sharedEdges = triangles.GetPairs().Where(t => t.first.IsAdjacentTo(t.second)).Count();
}
```

How can I only compare 1 triangle with the list to see how many shared edges 1 triangle has with the formation?

Comment: Have you looked into `IComparer<T>`?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to use my function with 1 triangle comparing to a list. Now I am comparing the full list with each other. Can you give me a sample code or something?

Comment: Also have you considered using `System.Drawing.Point` instead of defining each x and y as a property?

Comment: Yeah, its on my to-do list of changes... But for now I want to have this feature build in with just x and y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate the concept of `Triangle` out completely.  Trying to manage triangle point properties and maintain an adjacent ledger on the same class is going to complicate things as your code scales.

Here's a very rough design of how you could get started in this direction:

```
public class Triangle
{
    public PointF Point1 { get; }
    public PointF Point2 { get; }
    public PointF Point3 { get; }

    public IEnumerable<PointF> Points => new List<PointF> { Point1, Point2, Point3 };

    public Triangle(PointF point1, PointF point2, PointF point3)
    {
        this.Point1 = point1;
        this.Point2 = point2;
        this.Point3 = point3;
    }

    public Triangle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3)
        : this(new PointF(x1, y1), new PointF(x2, y2), new PointF(x3, y3)) { }

    public bool IsAdjacentTo(Triangle other) => this.Points.Intersect(other.Points).Count() > 1;
}

public class TriangleRegistryList
{
    public IList<Triangle> Triangles { get; }
    public Dictionary<Triangle, List<Triangle>> AdjacentMap { get; }

    public TriangleRegistryList(IEnumerable<Triangle> triangles)
    {
        this.Triangles = new List<Triangle>(triangles);
        this.AdjacentMap = GetAdjacentMap();
    }

    private Dictionary<Triangle, List<Triangle>> GetAdjacentMap()
    {
        return Triangles.ToDictionary(t => t, a => Triangles.Where(b => b.IsAdjacentTo(a)).ToList());
    }
}
```

This is not tested by any means, but you see the compartmentalizing of each respective class.

Comment: And what is the full line to call this function?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I'm simply showing the separation of responsibility in two classes rather than one.